# Is it possible to inject dimensions with Roboguice?

Tags: android, roboguice

Is something like this possible with Roboguice on Android?

```
<resources>
   <dimen name="radius">10dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

and then

```
@InjectResource(R.dimen.radius)
private int radius; // in px
```

Thanks!

Comment: Caught! Nothing really, beside that I thought it would be nice if it worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into [sources](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/master/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/inject/ResourceListener.java) and there are supported types as:

- `String resources.getString(id)`
- `boolean resources.getBoolean(id)`
- `ColorStateList resources.getColorStateList(id)`
- `int resources.getInteger(id)`
- `Drawable resources.getDrawable(id)`
- `String[] resources.getStringArray(id)`
- `int[] resources.getIntArray(id)`
- `Animation AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(application, id)`
- `Movie resources.getMovie(id)`

I couldn't find `int resources.getDimensionPixelSize(id)`.
That what you could do is to keep dimension as an `int` value:

```
<resources>
   <integer name="radius">10</integer>
</resources>
```

But it's not a clean solution.